# Terrain (mesh) textures in Unity - blurry?

Tags: unity, textures, mesh, materials

I've created a 3D mesh in blender which will be used as a terrain in Unity. Additionaly, I created a 900x900 texture which I'd like to apply as material to the mesh. However, unlike with the normal Unity terrain, the material is only blurry/unrecognizable, not matter how many times I repeat the texture/what import settings I set for the texture.

Some googling brought up that it may have to do something with the shader, but I tried many with no results.

### current result

[image: applied texture]

### texture

[image: texture]

Answer (score 1):

I think your model doesn't have texture coordinates. While Unity generates texture coordinates for its generated terrain. Unfortunately this is not the case with your exported model. What you need to do is to create UVs for your mesh in your modeling program.